# Get the folder name from a path

Tags: vb.net, path, directory

There is a directory whose name is temp. It contains various folders of different names. I want to delete the folder of specific name such as test. How to delete that in `vb.net`. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service (you only have luck sometimes). Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with following code and edit the code for your needs:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim directoryName As String = "D:\_working"
    Dim subPath = directoryName & "\TEST"  '// be careful - subPath will be deleted!

    Try
      Dim directoryExists = Directory.Exists("D:\_working")
      Dim subDirectoryExists = Directory.Exists(subPath)

      MessageBox.Show("top-level directory exists: " & directoryExists)
      MessageBox.Show("sub-directory exists: " & subDirectoryExists)

      For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(subPath, "*.BMP", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        File.Delete(deleteFile)
        '// you may want to log all deleted files here ...
      Next

      Directory.Delete(subPath) '// without the need of logging add ..(subPath, true) 

    Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show("The process failed: {0}", ex.Message)
    End Try

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Instead of iterating every file you can just call [**`Directory.Delete(subPath, True)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `Imports System.IO`

then you can just do this

```
File.Delete(path)
```

where path is a string equal to the value of your path.